# Stripping multiple characters from the start of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to trim a sub-string from the beginning of a string based on a condition:

For instance, if the input is a domain name prefixed with *http*, *https* and/or *www*, it needs to strip these and return only the domain.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if my_domain.startswith("http://"):
        my_domain = my_domain[7:]
elif my_domain.startswith("https://"):
        my_domain = my_domain[8:]

if my_domain.startswith("www."):
        my_domain = my_domain[4:]

print my_domain
```

I've tried to use these inbuilt functions (`.startswith`) instead of trying to use regex.

While the code above works, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to combine the conditions to make the code shorter or have multiple checks in the same conditional statement?

Answer (score 2):

I know regex is computationally slower than a lot of the built in methods but it is a lot easier to write code wise :)

```
import re
re.sub("http[s]*://|www\." , "", my_domain)
```

edit:
As mentioned by @Dunes a more correct way of answering this problem is.

```
re.sub(r"^https?://(www\.)?" , "" , my_domain)
```

Old answer left for reference so that Dunes comment still has some context.

Comment: This regex may end up removing unintended parts of the URL. First anchor the regex to the start, second use a single optional quantifier for `s` rather than `*`, thirdly make `www.` optional rather than part of an or group. New regex would look like: `r"^https?://(www\.)?"`. You could also use `subn` rather than `sub`.

Comment: @Dunes - All valid comments. I pad put the www as an or statement as I had misread the question and assumed he had links that started with  a www. that he wasn't interested in. Will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) (Python 3).

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> components = parse.urlsplit('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187220/stripping-multiple-characters-from-the-start-of-a-string')
>>> components[1]
'stackoverflow.com'
```

The Python 2.7 equivalent is named [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

To cover the `'www.'` case, you could simply do

```
* subdomains, domain, ending = components[1].split('.')
return '.'.join((domain, ending))
```

In Python 2.7 you don’t have access to `*` unpacking but you can use a list slice instead to get the same effect.

Comment: What about the case where the OP wants to remove any "www." prefix?

Comment: the resulting string is simple enough that you could simply run a split('.') operation on it if more than one dot was contained in the string. Added this to the answer